# Фильтрация в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Подскажите как реализовать фильтрацию mysql, создал таблицу в бд с 2умя колонками(id , marka_avto), вопрос как сделать так чтобы при выборе марки авто выпадал список с моделями авто конкретной марки, нужно ли создавать отдельную таблицу для моделей авто и какие там должны быть колонки?

пока что только выводятся значения из бд марка авто, делал так:

```
     <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                <option>марка</option>
                    <?php
                    //Выводим категории и ее ID
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                    $id = $row['id']; // иднтификатор
                           $marka = $row['marka_avto']; 

                           echo "<option value=\"$id\">$marka</option>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                  // Тут по идеи должна выводится модель авто в зависимости от выбранной марки
                    <select class="filtr__select" id="idcat">
                <option>модель</option>
                    <?php
                    //Выводим категории и ее ID
                    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                    $id = $row['id']; // иднтификатор
                           $model = $row['model_avto']; 

                           echo "<option value=\"$id\">$model</option>";

                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
              С бд раньше не работал поэтому интересует как спроектировать бд для такого фильтра, заранее спасибо
```

Answer (score 0):

Приближенная модель

Графическое представление в MySql Workbench

[image: Графическое представление в MySql Workbench]

Скрипт, созданный MySQL Workbench

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Brand`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Brand` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Model`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Model` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `BrandId` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  INDEX `fk_Model_Brand_idx` (`BrandId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Model_Brand`
    FOREIGN KEY (`BrandId`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Brand` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Car`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Car` (
  `Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ModelId` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  INDEX `fk_Car_Model1_idx` (`ModelId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Car_Model1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ModelId`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Model` (`Id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: А зачем нужны игрища с системными переменными? тем более что прав на их изменение может и не быть.